# How can I determine whether a POSIX app. is running within 5 minutes of system boot?

Tags: posix

From a C++ app. compiled for AIX, HP-UX, Linux, OSX and Solaris is there a simple way to determine whether the app. is running within 5 minutes of system boot?

On Windows I can do this:

```
// return true if OS has recently booted up
bool at_os_boot_time()
{
    /*  GetTickCount() returns the number of miliseconds since system start.
        So "...the time will wrap around to zero if the system is run 
        continuously for 49.7 days" - so this function will erroneously 
        return true for a 5 minute period 49.7 days after boot */
    return ::GetTickCount() < 5 * 60 * 1000;
}
```

I can't find the equivalent in the Unix world.

Answer (score 3):

this is from kernel.h on linux:

```
struct sysinfo;
extern int do_sysinfo(struct sysinfo *info);

#endif /* __KERNEL__ */

#define SI_LOAD_SHIFT   16
struct sysinfo {
    long uptime;            /* Seconds since boot */
    unsigned long loads[3];     /* 1, 5, and 15 minute load averages */
    unsigned long totalram;     /* Total usable main memory size */
    unsigned long freeram;      /* Available memory size */
    unsigned long sharedram;    /* Amount of shared memory */
    unsigned long bufferram;    /* Memory used by buffers */
    unsigned long totalswap;    /* Total swap space size */
    unsigned long freeswap;     /* swap space still available */
    unsigned short procs;       /* Number of current processes */
    unsigned short pad;     /* explicit padding for m68k */
    unsigned long totalhigh;    /* Total high memory size */
    unsigned long freehigh;     /* Available high memory size */
    unsigned int mem_unit;      /* Memory unit size in bytes */
    char _f[20-2*sizeof(long)-sizeof(int)]; /* Padding: libc5 uses this.. */
};
```

Answer (score 2):

At least in Linux you can use the [`sysinfo` system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sysinfo).

Answer (score 2):

The most portable method to determine the time of the last system boot is to use [`getutxid()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getutxid.html), with a `ut_type` of `BOOT_TIME`, to get it using the system accounting data.  I think that all of the systems you mentioned should support this, although it may not be particularly efficient.  You could also call a command line program like `uptime`, `who` `-b`, or `w`.

Some systems support a more efficient interface to get this information but it will be OS-specific.  Mac OS X (and FreeBSD) has the [`sysctl()`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctl.3.html) `CTL_KERN` `KERN_BOOTTIME`.  HP-UX has [`pstat_getstatic()`](http://docs.hp.com/en/B2355-90130/pstat.2.html).  Tru64 has [`table()`](http://www5.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/man2html?table%282%29) with the TBL_SYSINFO parameter.  As mentioned in another answer Linux has [`sysinfo()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html), but you can also read the time since boot from from [`/proc/uptime`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) (it is the first number).

Comment: getutxid requires that the utmp file be setup, correctly updated, not truncated, etc. On an embedded device, that's not a good bet. Getting the uptime from the kernel with sysinfo(2) is a much better plan.